# Visual Studio Code Version: 1:30.0 - How do I move Terminal output to the bottom

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't find this in the documentation. Currently, when I click Terminal > New Terminal, it appears to the right of the IDE. I prefer to see this at the bottom. How do I move it to the bottom please? I have looked but I do not understand all the Newspeak.

Comment: I believe if you right-click on the terminal there should be a "Move Panel to Bottom" option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right-click on Terminal and choose **`Move Panel to Bottom`** option, as you can see here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you go to settings there is an option to put the terminal on the bottom or right. You can change it there. If you are actually editting the settings.json file look for "workbench.panel.defaultLocation" statement and change it to "bottom"